# Kotlin Project Not Running Docker and Test M1 Mac

Tags: docker, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to run tests docker engine is not running at all. I'm using:

```
Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          15.0.7 (Azul Systems, Inc. 15.0.7+4-MTS)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.3.1 aarch64
```

Comment: This is merely a complaint and not a question; nothing one could reproduce.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.